# Issues when playing through bluetooth speaker (youtube mutes)

Tags: macos, itunes, audio, bluetooth, youtube

1. I listen to iTunes via Archt One BT speaker
2. I pause iTunes, try to play youtube video and there is no sound
3. while youtube stil playing "muted", I then play iTunes again and both can be heard
4. this doesn't happen with Swinsian (alternative to iTunes)

I'm on Mac OS Mavericks.

Any solution? Is it just an iTunes/OSX bug? I think it's not related to that particular BT speaker although it's with it that I experience this for the first time.. I don't remember if I used Swinsian or already back to iTunes when testing the previous speaker.

Comment: I have the exact same problem with a JBL Xtreme (macOS Mojave). I think the problem is with Chrome, it doesn't happen on Safari.

Comment: Apparently it's not Chrome specific. I have the same problem on Firefox.

Comment: I have a similar issue, only when Youtube is open. My bluetooth speaker would connect, but no sound, then it would disconnect. I've been having this issue for about a year now. It only happens when Youtube is open on Safari, but not on Chrome. Occasionally it works, but when it becomes persistent I use Chrome to watch Youtube.

Answer (score 2):

It's not really a solution, more like a work-around, but for me it helps if I

1. open *System-Preferences -> Sound -> Output*
2. switch Output to *Internal Speakers*
3. close iTunes if still open
4. switch Output back to your bluetooth connected device (sometimes the output sounds like being under water for a few seconds and than plays normal)

But yeah, it's really annoying. Seems like iTunes has a built-in "manage bluetooth" function, which you cannot switch off. Not using iTunes seems the best solution ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Play both through iTunes and YouTube so you can hear both and then press the play/pause button on your keypad. this should pause the iTunes music but still play the YouTube video sound. Then you can exit the iTunes app.

Hope it Helps!

Comment: Didn't work for me. I have the exact same problem with a JBL Xtreme (macOS High Sierra).

Answer (score 1):

Still happening on Mojave using bluetooth headphones, with Apple Music, Spotify & the browser. I've noticed that if you go into audio midi setup, and change the channel format from one option to another, and then back to the original highest setting, the headphones work again.

Answer (score 0):

Same happens with Safari and yes seems like some OS X bug

This also happens when f.ex. playing any youtube video while using Vox player. Pausing/closing youtube tab on Chrome/Safari stops sound in Vox. Same with f.ex. Itunes/Vox.. So yeah seemingly OSX issue.

Only thing I found to help was is switching bluetooth off and on again to reconnect to speakers, but I hope that someday there will be permanent solution, this bug bothers me already many years.

Comment: Mute in YouTube, then pause - works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue with bluetooth headphones and Safari. Whenever I pause video in YouTube or Facebook or similar, other sounds stop working (Cog player for example that I use for music, some voice call software as well).

My solution to this is to use youtube mute function (press "m" key) before pausing the video. Surprisingly, this prevents the "global" muting.

Answer (score 0):

And I still have the same problem with Jabra Evolve2 85, and Chrome Youtube video. MacOS 10.15.7. So annoying!